# How to validate hash password for old identity 2.0 tables with ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I've inherited an old application that users Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core v2.0 to authenticate against an existing database that was generated using migrations (.NET Framework 4.5 and Entity Framework 6).

Now I need to create a new application using .NET 6, EFCore 6, that uses the existing database tables to do the login without modifying the table schema (this is a non-negotiable requirement). I already replicated the model by doing a scaffolding of the needed AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles and AspNetUserRoles tables and I'm currently trying to implement my own login method, but when I try to hash the password, it doesn't generate the same password as the one found in the database (AspNetUsers table PasswordHash column).

I've tried the following:

- Use Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.PasswordHasher to generate the hash:

```
var hasher = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.PasswordHasher();
var hash = hasher.HashPassword("password123");
```

- Use ASP.NET Core's PasswordHasher with compatibility to Identity V2

```
PasswordHasher<AspNetUser> hasher = new PasswordHasher<AspNetUser>(
    new OptionsWrapper<PasswordHasherOptions>(
        new PasswordHasherOptions() {
            CompatibilityMode = PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode.IdentityV2
        })
);
var hash = hasher.HashPassword(user, "password123");
```

- Even attempted to replicate from the source code I found [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/tree/main/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core):

```
int PBKDF2IterCount = 1000; // default for Rfc2898DeriveBytes
int PBKDF2SubkeyLength = 256 / 8; // 256 bits
int SaltSize = 128 / 8; // 128 bits
byte[] salt;
byte[] subkey;
using (var deriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes("password123", SaltSize, PBKDF2IterCount)) {
    salt = deriveBytes.Salt;
    subkey = deriveBytes.GetBytes(PBKDF2SubkeyLength);
}

var outputBytes = new byte[1 + SaltSize + PBKDF2SubkeyLength];
Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, 0, outputBytes, 1, SaltSize);
Buffer.BlockCopy(subkey, 0, outputBytes, 1 + SaltSize, PBKDF2SubkeyLength);
var hash = Convert.ToBase64String(outputBytes);
```

But none of this options work. The old app uses a class that inherits from `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` to create users, which apparently uses the `PasswordHasher` I mentioned above, so as far as I can tell they both should generate the same hash, but they aren't.

Is there something I'm missing, or should I try another approach, or how I'm supposed to use properly the PasswordHasher? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't expect the passwordhash could be the same

Even if you try as below with .net core Identity:

Regist with  Email/Password=>copy the password hash in DB=>Delete current user=> Regist with same Email/Password =>check the password hash again

you would found the two passwordhash are different

I tried as below to validate a passwordhash generated by .net framework methods in a .net core app:

```
builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
                services.AddDbContext<IdentityProjContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(
                        context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityProjContextConnection")));

                services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => {
                    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
                    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
                   
                })
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityProjContext>();

                //services.Configure<PasswordHasherOptions>(x => x.CompatibilityMode = PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode.IdentityV2);
            });
```

Regist:

```
//Core 
 var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);

//framwork 
var userStore = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser>();
var manager = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser>(userStore);
var frameworkuser = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser() { UserName = Input.Email };
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityResult frameworkresult = manager.Create(frameworkuser, Input.Password);
```

copy  passwordhash  created bt .net framework to database:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then login:
[image]

It succeeded

performed the same  as mentioned in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-7.0#password-hasher-options)

> A client is able to authenticate regardless of which version of the
> algorithm was used to hash the password

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I tried your code, but I'm getting an error saying that ConfigureServices does not exist. But there is a builder.Services.Configure, is this the same?

Comment: Also, does your answer mean I have to use the latest identity? If so that's a problem because the IdentityUser in the newest version has more fields than what is available on my table, and as such it would require me to update the table, which is not something I can do...

Comment: What I tried just check  if compatibility mode used when hashing new passwords would affect the result when it read password from passwordhash,in fact I tried in vs2019,.net 5,but .net 5,.net 6 both hash password with IdentityV3,.net framework hash password in IdentityV2,I would update my codes to .net 6 version later

Comment: How to validate hash password for old identity 2.0 ---It could validate  hash password even if it works with   IdentityV3 now,as the document mentioned,but you shouldn't exptect the password hash would be the same

Comment: the IdentityUser in the newest version has more fields than what is available on my table---- check this document  :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configure-identity-and-membership   ,if you still don't know howto migrate,then update your db in question ,we won't know  the structure of  your db  untill you share it